# Getting ec2 instance ID suddenly stopped working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've been getting an amazon instance ID from within the instance itself for over a year now by hitting this local web address `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`. This is the appropriate method according to the AWS documentation. For some reason though, just this week that same call started throwing an error.

I tried pinging the `169.254.169.254` address from the command line and that fails, so it seems like something pretty basic has changed with the EC2 instances. I don't see any changes to the documentation on AWS. One thing I do notice is that I used to see the instance name in the upper right hand corner when loading up the instance and logging in remotely. That information doesn't appear anymore.

Here is the code I've been using to get the ID:

```
retID = New StreamReader(HttpWebRequest.Create("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id").GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()
```

Here is the full error stack:

```
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

   at RunControllerInterface.NewRunControlCommunicate.getInstanceIDFromAmazon()
```

The error message itself says: Unable to connect to the remote server

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that's actually the full error stack.

Comment: Edited to add extra line of the error stack

Comment: Surely your error stack at least includes an error *message*?

Comment: Ping is not a good test. If it is a Linux instance, use `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`. If it is Windows, open a web browser, turn off the IEC security stuff, and go to that URL. If the instance is unable to reach that URL, then there is some form of Firewall on the instance that is blocking traffic. If you wish to test behaviour, you can launch another instance and confirm that it works there, then try and figure out what is different.

Comment: I added the specific error message, which states that it was 'Unable to connect to the remote server'.

Comment: I also did take John's suggestion and try to turn off the IEC security stuff and then hit that address, which then returned the instance ID just fine.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I have at least a partial answer to this problem. When making this image, I was using a t3a.medium instance. As long as I use that same type of instance I am able to pull down the instance name.

Comment: It's almost certainly nothing to do with the instance type. It's going to be caused by some firewall or iptables rule on the instance that is blocking HTTP access to  169.254.169.254.